# App para mostrar Logcat nos dispositivos android

Tags: android

Eu gostaria de saber se existe algum aplicativo que mostre o Logcat dos erros dos apps android. 
Gostaria de otimizar o sistema de QA da empresa e isso ajudaria demais!

Comment: Sim, existe: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1513166. Nota: A partir do Android 4.1 qualquer app de logcat precisa de acesso root para mostrar os logs corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tiver acesso ao fonte do app, você consegue implementar e visualizar informações de logs utilizando algumas bibliotecas. Para log: https://github.com/hypertrack/hyperlog-android
Outra opção é o uso do Fabric (https://fabric.io/) que grava seus crashs em uma plataforma online, para cada usuário que tiver problema.

Caso não tenha acesso ao fonte, fica mais complicado, mas é possível verificar através do Android Studio.

Para esse leitura de logcat, se tiver algum app, precisará de ter o aparelho como root.